# WPF - Make two controls the same size

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, height

Is there any way to make two controls that are in different containers the same size in WPF?  For example, suppose you have two textboxes: textbox1 and textbox2.  Textbox1 is in a grid and its size can grow and shrink when the user resizes the window.  Textbox2 is in another part of the window and I need it to always have the same size as textbox1.  Is there any way to do this?

Keep in mind `SharedSizeGroup` will not work because the textboxes are in different containers.  Also, I've tried binding textbox2's height property to textbox1 and that doesn't seem to work either.  Finally, I tried catching textbox1's `SizeChanged` event, but its `Height` property is always NaN for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should bind to `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight` members of the `TextBox`.